# How to order field names by their "natural" order?

Tags: sql, oracle

For a little utility that I am writing I am listing all the field names of a table using:

```
select cols.column_name
from user_tab_columns cols
where cols.table_name = 'table_name_here';
```

While this works fine it lists the names in some odd order (almost random, it's not alphabetical nor inverse alphabetical or such but at least its always the same).

How can I enforce the "natural" order, i.e. the order in which the fields were defined and are e.g. listed in SQLDeveloper?

i.e.:

> ... order by ???

Answer (score 4):

The `column_id` column gives the order for the columns:

```sql
select column_name, column_id
from   user_tab_columns
where  cols.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME_HERE'
order by column_id
```

So if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name_here( a int, c int, d int, b int );
```

then the top query would output:

> ```
> COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_ID
> :---------- | --------:
> A           |         1
> C           |         2
> D           |         3
> B           |         4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b2deef6291455152f96c6f6a84ab830c)*

Comment: Thanks! You were pretty quick! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Looking closer I spotted that there is a column called "column_id" which holds that order. Beats me why I overlooked that at first.
Thus:

```
select * 
from user_tab_columns cols
where cols.table_name = 'table_name_here'
order by cols.column_id;
```

did the trick!

Sorry for the bandwidth consumed!

Comment: Agreed, `column_id` has never been the most obvious name for what it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
select c.owner, c.table_name, c.column_name, c.column_id
  from all_tab_cols c
 where owner = 'your_owner'  
   and table_name = 'your_table'
 order by column_id ; -- <==this is the id of column in the order it was created
```